# How to unit test when importing an instance of a Class in sinon and Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, sinon

How do I create a unit test for employeeService.ts. I am using sinon and typscript. I am able to mock it but the operations like database access is still running in the background. Please help. Here is the simplified code:

../utils/employeeInfo.ts:

```
    class employeeInfo {
  
      private memoizedResult: any = null;

      public async getResult() {
 
         if(!memoizeResult) {
            
           this.memoizeResult = await this.getData();
          }
          return memoizeResult; 
       }

    async getData() {

      // get data from database
      console.log('getting data from database');
      return data;
    }

    const EmployeeInfo = new employeeInfo();

    EmployeeInfo.getResult();
    
    export default EmployeeInfo;
```

employeeService.ts

```
import EmployeeInfo from '../utils/employeeInfo';

class employeeService { 

  async getSalary() {
   
     const data = await EmployeeInfo.getData()
     console.log(data);

  }
}

export default employeeService
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did you mock it?